# SSRS Data Driven Subscription - Create only one instance of report

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a report using SSRS and created a data driven subscription for it. Delivery method is email. Render format is MHTML. There are no parameters for the report. I cannot change the delivery method - it has to go through email itself. Users need to see the report as they preview the mail (rather than having to click a link and see it).

I can see that the data driven subscription creates the report afresh for each person. This causes two problems.

1) When the subscription works, there is a difference in the data between the first person who receives the report and the last person who receives it. This is because, it takes some time for sending to all persons and in the meanwhile data of database changes. How can I send the same report - report prepared for the first person - to all ? Something like a report snapshot. The data changes in it after that is irrelevant.

2) Since it creates the report each time it is sent, this causes huge performance issue - server hangs sometimes. This is the main reason I would like to prevent recreation of the report for each person.

May I know whether this is possible ? If yes, how ?

Many thanks,

Madhu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

You should use a shared dataset and set the dataset to cache. This means that the query will only run once for each report run, all the data will be the same and performance should be much better.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee636149.aspx

Comment: Hi Sam, Many thanks. I am not sure what is shared dataset. I am using a shared data source. However, not seeing any cache option for it. Will explore the article. Thanks.

Comment: I got what it shared dataset. It worked. Many thanks.